# Gstreamer RSTP server

Tags: gstreamer, gst-launch

I want to setup a RTSP server stream with Gstreamer 1.0 (gst-launch-1.0).

My "Server" currently looks like this

```
gst-launch-1.0.exe videotestsrc  ! x264enc ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=localhost port=5000
```

And my Client looks like this

```
gst-launch-1.0.exe udpsrc port=5000 ! rtpmp2tdepay ! decodebin ! autovideosink
```

Both commands run without errors, but I do not see any video on the "client". Moreover I'm aware that my commands are just streaming H.264 encoded video via RTP to a UDP port.

I see some data coming on UDP port 5000, so I assume that the sender part is correct.

My questions:

1. What am I doing wrong on the receiver side?
2. How can I setup gst-launch-1.0 to provide a RTSP stream (with the meta-information .sdp file)?

Edit (2014-03-24):
Debug output of sending side:

```
gst-launch-1.0.exe -v videotestsrc ! x264enc ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=localhost port=5000
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoTestSrc:videotestsrc0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, framerate=(fraction)30/1, width=(int)320, height=(int)240, format=(string)I420, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstX264Enc:x264enc0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, framerate=(fraction)30/1, width=(int)320, height=(int)240, format=(string)I420, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive
Redistribute latency...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstX264Enc:x264enc0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-h264, codec_data=(buffer)01640014ffe1001967640014acd94141fb0110000003001000000303c8f142996001000568ebecb22c, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)2, profile=(string)high, width=(int)320, height=(int)240, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)30/1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH264Pay:rtph264pay0.GstPad:src: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, sprop-parameter-sets=(string)"Z2QAFKzZQUH7ARAAAAMAEAAAAwPI8UKZYA\=\=\,aOvssiw\=", payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)383435573, timestamp-offset=(uint)786392204, seqnum-offset=(uint)781
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSink:udpsink0.GstPad:sink: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, sprop-parameter-sets=(string)"Z2QAFKzZQUH7ARAAAAMAEAAAAwPI8UKZYA\=\=\,aOvssiw\=", payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)383435573, timestamp-offset=(uint)786392204, seqnum-offset=(uint)781
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH264Pay:rtph264pay0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, codec_data=(buffer)01640014ffe1001967640014acd94141fb0110000003001000000303c8f142996001000568ebecb22c, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)2, profile=(string)high, width=(int)320, height=(int)240, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)30/1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH264Pay:rtph264pay0: timestamp = 786392204
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH264Pay:rtph264pay0: seqnum = 781
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
```

The receiving side:

```
gst-launch-1.0.exe -vvv udpsrc port=5000 ! "application/x-rtp, media=video, clock-rate=90000, encoding-name=H264, payload=96" ! queue ! rtph264depay ! queue ! decodebin ! autovideosink sync=false
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Problem #1.** You are using `rtph264pay` on sending side but `rtpmp2tdepay` on the receiving. You need to use `rtph264depay`.

**Problem #2.** You need to provide capabilities for `rtph264depay` to correctly recognize video format.
To get correct capabilities just run sending code with `-v` flag and copy rtp-specific caps to the receiving pipeline.

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5000 ! "application/x-rtp, media=video, clock-rate=90000, encoding-name=H264, payload=96" ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! autovideosink
```

Comment: Following your 2 problem solutions, it still does not work: gst-launch-1.0.exe -vvv udpsrc port=5000 ! "application/x-rtp, media=video, clock-rate=90000, encoding-name=H264, payload=96" ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! autovideosink I do not see a video window popping up. I fact there is almost no logs (even if I set the -vvv parameter). Do you have any further hints?

Comment: Have you copied capabilities from the debug output of the *sending* pipeline?

Comment: Please update your question with debug output of the sending pipeline.

Comment: I've added the logs. Yes, I've taken the caps from the sending side (the x-rtp one).

Comment: Nothing is wrong with you new pipelines (except maybe couple of useless `queue`s). This could be some windows related problem (or firewall settings), I'am of no help here. Sorry.

Comment: Maybe one more note: Do you know how to create a RTSP stream with gstreamer? I'd like to have a SDP file generated.

Comment: Your solution does work. I've changed localhost to loopback IP (127.0.0.1) and now it works. But still, do you also have an answer to the RTSP?

Comment: There is [gst-rtsp-server](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/modules/gst-rtsp-server.html) project but I have no experience with it.